# How to serialize an object containing an XML property

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, .net-4.8

**Note this is .NET 4.8**

I have created this sample code to illustrate the problem

```cs
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "RESULT", Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public class Result
{
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public XElement Stuff { get; set; }


    public override string ToString() 
    {
        var ser = new XmlSerializer(GetType());

        using (var stream = new StringWriter())
        {
            ser.Serialize(stream, this);
            return stream.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

I will have some `XML` already that looks like this

```xml
<FOO>
      <BAR>Hello World</BAR>
      <BAR2>Hello World</BAR2>
      <BAR3>Hello World</BAR3>
</FOO>
```

This is assigned to the `XElement Stuff` property and when an instance of `Result` is then serialized, you get this XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<RESULT xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Message>Hello World</Message>
  <Stuff>
    <FOO>
      <BAR>Hello World</BAR>
      <BAR2>Hello World</BAR2>
      <BAR3>Hello World</BAR3>
    </FOO>
  </Stuff>
</RESULT>
```

Question: Is there any way to get this result instead?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<RESULT xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Message>Hello World</Message>
  <FOO>
    <BAR>Hello World</BAR>
    <BAR2>Hello World</BAR2>
    <BAR3>Hello World</BAR3>
  </FOO>
</RESULT>
```

*Note: `FOO` could be `Stuff` - I don't care (because I know how to change that name) I just don't want two levels of nested XML for that property in the serialised XML*

[You can play with the sample code here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2v1Xun)

Comment: Why do you mix traditional XML serializer with XML to LINQ?

Comment: @PeterCsala Do you mean using XElement in the class?

Comment: Yes, I meant that.

Comment: I think this is just how serialisation works - the generated serialiser for `Result` will write the start of the `Stuff` element, then delegate to the serialiser for `XElement`, then write the end of the element. To change this, you might have to implement `IXmlSerializable` in `Result`, which isn't ideal - though, with your example, not too hard.

Comment: Just find the syntax for XElement manipulation works for me - if changing it would help, that would be fine...

Comment: @CharlesMager So, that sounds like I could use a custom type for `Stuff` and maybe write custom serializer for that custom type - to get what I want?

Comment: No, you'd need to write the custom serialisation in `Result` - as I explain, it's the generated serialiser for `Result` that writes `<Stuff>` and `</Stuff>` (based on the property name or any attribute).

Comment: Sure, but I can change the name of Stuff with an attribute, it the serialized content I want to change (by excluding the root node) - maybe?

Comment: You can change its name, yes, but it's fixed. Perhaps I'm missing what your intention is here?

Comment: No, I'm sure you understand, I'm just trying to understand your response - I'll go look at IXmlSerializable  - thanks

Comment: If you're happy for `FOO` to be hardcoded, [would this work](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pyY04i)? `ReadXml` not implemented. If not, then it's `Result` where you'll need to implement (where it could be more complicated if the 'real' type has more than 2 properties).

Comment: Dirty but working solution. 1) Add `[XmlIgnore]` to `Stuff` property 2) Replace your `return` statement inside `ToString` to this: `var doc = XDocument.Parse(stream.ToString());` `doc.Descendants("Message").First().AddAfterSelf(Stuff);` `return doc.ToString();`

Comment: @CharlesMager - Yes, thanks - that's just what I was in the process of writing, so good to know how you did it. If you could post an answer, I'll accept.  Thank you! PeterCsala - thanks - that is something I'll skip this time, but appreciate your input 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're happy for the root name to be hard-coded, then you can write a wrapper type for the elements and implement `IXmlSerializable` within.

This is likely preferable to implementing in `Result`, as I imagine the real type would have more than 2 properties.

A quick and dirty example - I'll leave implementing `ReadXml` to you (if you need it):

```
public class ElementsWrapper : IXmlSerializable
{   
    public XElement[] Elements { get; set; }

    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        foreach (var element in Elements)
        {
            element.WriteTo(writer);
        }
    }
}
```

And change your property in `Result` to:

```
public ElementsWrapper FOO { get; set; }
```

When used, the serialiser for `Result` will write `<FOO>`, then delegate to the custom serialisation, and then write `</FOO>`.

You can see an updated fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pyY04i).

Comment: So easy once you know how - wish getting the person writing these requirements to change them was as easy! - Thanks very much